# Any other bound state problems using $a_+$ and $a_-$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators

Why is it that creation and annihilation operators ($a_+$ and $a_-$) can only be defined for the problem of quantum harmonic oscillator and nothing else? Can any other bound state problem be solves using $a_+$ and $a_-$?

Comment: Harmonic oscillator is not alone. There's also [angular momentum eigenstate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladder_operator#Angular_momentum) problem, where ladder operators are useful.

Answer (score 4):

The point is that, if you have a pair of operators $a,a^\dagger$ such that on a common invariant domain $S$,
$[a,a^\dagger]= I$, $a^\dagger$ is the restriction of the adjoint of $a$ on $S$ and, in $S$, there is a unique vector $|0\rangle$ with $a|0\rangle=0$, then the closure 
space spanned by the $|n\rangle$ is isomorphic to $L^2(\mathbb R)$. In that space "there is the harmonic oscillator" constructed in the standard way. So, you cannot get rid of the existence of the harmonic oscillator in our Hilbert space.  What could happen is that, for some reason, the Hamiltonian of your system is not proportional to $a^\dagger a$ but to something  more complicated, or that there are many vectors verifying $a\Psi =0$, so that the closure of the span of $|n\rangle$ does not exhaust the whole Hilbert space (this is the situation in free QFT).

Comment: It seems you've understood the question as "why does harmonic oscillator exist". But it's in fact "is there any other bound state problem solvable via ladder operators than harmonic oscillator".

Comment: No, I have understood, I think. My point is: if you are able to use $a,a^\dagger$ to rigorously solve a problem, actually there must be an harmonic oscillator hidden therein. Perhaps coupled with other physical systems (Hydrogen atom levels), or accompanied by other similar oscillators (free quantum fields)...I am strictly referring to the algebra of $a$ and $a^\dagger$ here, not for instance to that of $J_\pm$, or similar operators in CFT used to construct Virasoro's algebra representations.

Comment: Wow, now your answer appears much more interesting than I thought :)